# Jquery, Set function arguments in callback

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm trying to write my first jquery plugin but I'm running into some difficulties.

Code snippets:

Here I am initializing my plugin and setting the function that should execute when MyEvent occurs.

```
$("#myMap").MyPlugin({ myEvent: function() { alert("test"); } });
```

And this is the function in my plugin script

```
function setEvents(options) {
            $.each(options, function(event, fn) {
                if (typeof (fn) == 'function') {
                    if (event == "myEvent") {
                        $(myDiv).click(fn);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
```

This works fine, but I want to retrieve information from the plugin while the even occurs.
Basically I want to receive a parameter I have set in that "setEvents" function.

```
$("#myMap").MyPlugin({ myEvent: function(myParam) { alert(param); } });
```

I cant seem to figure this one out, can someone point me in the right direction.

**UPDATE:** a more complete snippet of my current plugin script

```
(function($) {
    var defaults = {
        width: 300,
        height: 300,
        myEvent: null
    };

    $.fn.myPlugin = function(options) {
        var options = $.extend(defaults, options); 
        var myDiv = $(this);
        return this.each(function() {
            setEvents(options);
        });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be complete code. please post complete code.

Comment: I don't follow. What precisely do you want what to be able to access? can you edit to provide a clearer example?

Comment: @BBQ, do you want a specific parameter to be passed to your handler, or do you want it to receive the whole `options` hash?

Comment: It's not the neatest code I've ever written since I'm trying some things out. But handler only needs options.myEvent which would make the loop unnecessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the `myEvent` event is mapped to a `click` event by your plugin, you can pass a parameter map to [click()](http://api.jquery.com/click/) in order for it to be ultimately passed to your handler:

```
if (typeof(fn) == "function") {
    if (event == "myEvent") {
        $(myDiv).click({
            param: myParam
        }, fn);
    }
}
```

Then you can write:

```
$("#myMap").MyPlugin({
    myEvent: function(event) {
        alert(event.data.param);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Frederic. It works with a little tweak. I had to change it to 'args.data.param'.  Is there an easy way to go around the parameter map thing, and just receive a string as parameter?

Comment: @BBQ, unfortunately, jQuery handlers are designed to receive a single parameter hash that is transmitted through the `event` object (I used the wrong name in my answer, this is now fixed). You can pass a single value in that hash, but there has to be a hash around it.